# C# double is cast as a string

Tags: c#

In C# I have the following code and I cant work out why my double values get rendered as a string?
When I try to add Tax to Total it reverts to a string?

```
        double Total = 0;
        double Tax = 0;

        foreach (var Product in ProductList)
        {
            if (Product.Taxable)  Tax = Tax + (Product.Price * .1) ;
            Total = Total + (Product.Price * Product.Qty);
            Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} at {2}", Product.Qty, Product.Item, Product.Price.ToString("C"), Product.Taxable, Product.Exempt);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Sales Taxes: " + Tax.ToString("C"));            
        Console.WriteLine("Total: " + Total.ToString("C"));
        
        Console.WriteLine("Taxes: " + Total + Tax);
```

Comment: What's `ProductList` definition

Comment: Are you referring to the line `Console.WriteLine("Taxes: " + Total + Tax);` and why it would concatenate the values rather than do addition?

Comment: You should accept the answer if you find that it solves your problem

Comment: Just a note – since you are working with money, you should be using the `decimal` type for all your dollar values (and `.1`).This will save you from floating-point errors later, where you may find you end up with something like $1.9999999999999 when you expected $2.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is because in C# the + operator evaluates from left to right:

```
"Taxes: " + Total + Tax
```

first it does `"Taxes: " + Total` which makes it a string: `"Taxes: 1.23"` and then it does: `"Taxes: 1.23" + Tax` which results in `"Taxes: 1.232.34"` for example.

To fix it calculate the sum before or add brackets:

```
"Taxes: " + (Total + Tax)
```

or

```
var sum = Total + Tax
"Taxes: " + sum
```

Comment: "Sequentially" really isn't the right term. It might be more accurate to say "both `+` operators have the same [precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-language/precedence-and-order-of-evaluation?view=msvc-160), and all plus operators evaluate from left to right (because that's how that operator works)"

Comment: @DStanley, gunr2171, Updated the wording as per your suggestions.

Comment: Or `$"Taxes: {Total + Tax}";`

Comment: Thank you guys, works like a charm now!

Comment: And with interpolated strings like @DmitryBychenko suggests, you can still include a format string, for example `$"Total: {Total:C}"` or `$"Taxes: {Total + Tax:C}"`. So you do not have to type `.ToString` even if you want to specify the format.